# How to set up multiple conditions by using switch?

Tags: php

I want to code a counting game on php.
The rule is like the following:
1. Player selects a number from 0~3
2. Computer selects a number from player's selection + 0~3 
3. The one arrive 30 lose the game

The code I have written :

```
<?php  
$total = $_POST['total']; 
$user_number = $_POST['number']; // 1~3
$total='';
switch ($total){
case '4':
case '8':
case '12':
case '16':
case '20':
case '24':
case '28':
    $computer_selection = 1;
    break;
case '3':
case '7':
case '12':
case '16':
case '20':
case '23':
case '27':
    $computer_selection = 2;
    break;
case '2':
case '6':
case '11':
case '15':
case '19':
case '22':
case '26':
    $computer_selection = 3;
    break;
default:
    $computer_selection =1;
    break;
}
$computer_number = $total + $computer_selection;
$total = $user_number + $computer_number;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>恐怖の３０ゲーム</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php print_r('The choice of computer'.$computer_number.'<br>'); ?>
<?php print_r('Current number:'.$total.'<br>'); ?>
恐怖の３０
<?php
$total_nubmer1=$total+1;
$total_number2=$total+2;
$total_number3=$total+3;
?>
<form method='post' action='index2.php'>
    you：
    <select name='number'></br>
        <option value='<?php echo $total_nubmer1 ?>'><?php echo
$total_nubmer1 ?></option>
        <option value='<?php echo $total_number2 ?>'><?php echo 
$total_number2 ?></option>
        <option value='<?php echo $total_number3 ?>'><?php echo 
$total_number3 ?></option>
    </select>
    <input type='hidden' name='total' value='<?php $total?>'>
    <input type='submit' value='登録'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
if ($user_number>=30){
echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">alert(\"you lose\");location.href='index.php';</script>";
}else if($user_number<=29 && $user_number>28||$total>29){
echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">alert(\"you win\");location.href='index.php'</script>";
}
?>
```

I dont't understand why the output at computer_selection always goes to default.

Comment: That's too verbose.  Use math.  You are overwriting the submitted value with an empty string.  This is a typo question that will not benefit future researchers.  You should have echoed the value to see for yourself.

Comment: Using `$total='';` before the switch doesn't help.

Comment: @mickmackusa I've just started to learn last month. After the task be able to run, I will try to make it shorter....$computer_number = $total + $computer_selection;
$total = $user_number + $computer_number; $total did work when I echo the result...but  it doesnt work on $computer_number...I dont see the logic here. Why there is a value inside $total but the value goes in to $computer_number always be 1 ...!?

Comment: @NigelRen Delete it now....Thank you ...

Comment: It is important that you not damage your question details.  Your code is important.

Comment: Do you see then next typo in you 2nd set of cases? `12`, `16`, `20`. This is a compelling reason to explore a mathematic approach.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry I need to damage the code since my manager might find it. They dont have time to teach me but asking other is also not allowed...

Comment: @mickmackusa yeah I know... but I want it be able to work at this stage...and then I will have those code to be simple. Thank you !

Comment: Honestly, my close vote on this question is not indicative of my interest in helping.  I'm actually intrigued by this project.  I have seen this "game" before and know that the user should never win.  I like thinking about the coding design.  I think the best thing is to pass the user's value instead of the total (for simpler math), and pass the total as the hidden value.  Keep thinking about striving for the simplest logical design, then write the actual code.

Comment: I've solved this crazy problem. The main problem for the result of ' computer_selection ' is ....I forgot to echo $total when setting the HTML input value. Thanks for help !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Because you put this : `$total='';` just before the switch.
So, the $total always enter in the default case of your switch.

Comment: I thought $total='’’ refers to the empty blank ...and the result will automatically put inside if it fills the need of the case. Also, I have tried to delete  $total=''; or move the switch function to the under of $computer_selection; however, it shows the error that variable is undefined.... totally confused now...

Comment: You can put something like that : `if(isset($_POST['total'])) { $total = $_POST['total']; } else { $total='';}`

Comment: Or short, `$total = isset($_POST['total']) ? $_POST['total'] : '';`

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the value of `$total` before entering to the `switch`. Another thing that you are doing is assuming that the value of `$total` is recieved in the $_POST param, you shoul check if the value is set first. So remove the `$total = '';` line and do something like this in your assignment

```
$total = (isset($_POST['total']))?$_POST['total']:'';
```

Same goes for number. That way if nothing is recieved it will go default.

Hope it helps!